# jquery slider having different max values not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

html file

```
<h1>HTML Slider Test</h1>
<div class="slider">
    <script>
        var a=10;
    </script>
</div>
<p>Your slider has a value of 
    <span class="slider-value"></span>
</p>
<div class="slider">
    <script>
        var a=100;
    </script>
</div>
<p>Your slider has a value of 
    <span class="slider-value"></span>
</p>
```

jquery file

```
$(".slider").slider({
    value: 1,
    min: 0,
    max: a,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).next().find('span.slider-value').html(ui.value);
    }
});

$(".slider-value").html($('.slider').slider('value'));
```

i am currently having two scripts in two div's but the a has value of 10 and 100 and it is assigned to max value of slider.but a=10 is not working both sliders are showing 100 as max.but i want first max as 10 and second as 100.

http://jsfiddle.net/s7uxtbu7/2/

Comment: You've completely misunderstood how this works,  setting a variable in a script tag inside the slider does nothing and isn't even remotely related  to the way the options object is passed to the slider plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that actually works, using a data attribute in the HTML

```
<h1>HTML Slider Test</h1>

<div class="slider" data-max="10"></div>

<p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>

<div class="slider" data-max="100"></div>

<p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>
```

and then getting that value for each slider

```
$(".slider").each(function() {
    $(this).slider({
        value : 1,
        min   : 0,
        max   : $(this).data('max'),
        step  : 1,
        slide : function (event, ui) {
            $(this).next().find('span.slider-value').html(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/s7uxtbu7/3/)

Comment: Dammit! 16 seconds too late :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Sorry, looks like we had the same idea, and it's probably what makes most sense from the OP's code.

Comment: provide a jsfiddle pls